# How to add a key to an empty schema?

Tags: dconf, gsettings

I would like to  automate setting some settings, specifically add some keyboard shortcuts to `~/.config/dconf/user`.  Here is how it looks in dconf-editor:

[image: org.cinnamon.keybindings]
[image: org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybindings.custom0]

Now gsettings (or dconf) can list the first one:

```
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.keybindings custom-list
['custom0', 'custom1', 'custom2', 'custom3']
```

However, I cannot see a way to then add a new keybinding, or even to read the `customX` keys.

```
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/ custom0
No such key 'custom0'
```

How can I add, for example, a `custom4` key with `binding='<Super>g'`, `command='geany'`, `name='Geany'`?

### Output to Donarssons answer:

```
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybindings:/custom0/ binding
No such schema 'org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybindings'
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/custom0/ binding
''
```

And screenshot after the following command. Note that custom4 does not go to custom-keybindings but to the root.

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/custom4/ binding '<Super>g'
```

[image: gsetting the value]

I'm using Linux Mint as my O/S.

Comment: This is NOT off-topic, the question is fully applicable to Cinnamon on Ubuntu and mostly valid for Unity and GNOME (the schemas are named differently there, but the names are of no concern for the actual issue described here).

Comment: @Donarsson anything about Mint, even if it applies to Ubuntu is off topic, otherwise we would be accepting Debian questions just because they apply to Ubuntu in some cases. If you had read the comments on the accepted answer you would notice that "ubuntu guys" wasn't able to deal effectively with the question since there was missing information. Further discussions bring them to meta.

Comment: I agree that the specific example of setting a cinnamon keyboard shortcut is not Ubuntu. The question though is how to _add a key to an empty schema_ in dconf, and dconf is not Ubuntu specific.

Comment: Yes that is all true and relevant, even for the zillions of tools that are common to all the Linux distros out there, `but org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybindings` is Mint specific and does not exist in Ubuntu.

Comment: I could recreate the screenshots and everything in Ubuntu and edit the question and answer accordingly, if that helps. Then it might be useful for other Ubuntu users in the future.

Comment: @Donarsson Fire away.

Comment: @Donarsson Please, go for it.

Comment: @Braiam Stop it. Just stop it. Oli is fine with it.  Besides, updating the screenshots isn't going to change the question. It's about dconf not Mint.

Comment: @Seth [migrate it then](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8644/169736)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a syntax error. This should work:

```
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding
<Super>e
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command
nemo
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name
nemo
```

To set a new hotkey:

```
$ gsettings set org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom4/ binding '<Super>g' &&
gsettings set org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom4/ command 'geany' &&
gsettings set org.cinnamon.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom4/ name 'Geany'
```

Comment: Were you going to update the screenshots? I know you mentioned it above.

Comment: What if the schema `custom-keybindings` does not exist yet (for setting a new hotkey)?

Comment: I [resolved my issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/1234103/606260), nevermind :)